# Regular Expression PHP preg_match_all

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

I'm a self-thought PHP beginner and I'm still learning regular expressions. Here is a problem i encountered with `preg_match_all` and arrays

my array has exactly the following information:

```
;;CARLOS||ANDREW||STEPH||SUE||JUDY||HAROLD||JAMES||KATIE||JESSICA;;
```

What i'm trying to do is display each name individually there are about 250 different names, the array always begins with ;; and always ends with ;; so here is my issue, first my array loads fine but only the first name by doing:

```
    preg_match_all('/^(.+?)\|\|/', $body, $part);
    foreach ($part[1] as $part){
    print_r($part);
```

Result is `;;CARLOS`

Where `$body` is the huge list of names (array with 250+ names).

Desired result:

```
CARLOS
ANDREW
STEPH
JUDY
HAROLD
JAMES
KATIE
JESSICA
```

Please understand i cannot change the input array, it is what it is. So basically on the first array i have load the entire list then i need to break it by | characters.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have you looked at [explode()](http://php.net/explode) and `str_replace` to remove the semicolons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use regular expressions here. [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will work just fine.

```
$str = trim($body, ";");    // Remove semi-colons
$arr = explode("||", $str); // Return array of strings delimited by double pipes

print_r($arr);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => CARLOS
    [1] => ANDREW
    [2] => STEPH
    [3] => SUE
    [4] => JUDY
    [5] => HAROLD
    [6] => JAMES
    [7] => KATIE
    [8] => JESSICA
)
```

[See in action.](http://codepad.org/xac42hTm)

If you want your *desired result* exactly, then [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the above output.

```
echo implode(" ", $arr);
// Outputs: CARLOS ANDREW STEPH SUE JUDY HAROLD JAMES KATIE JESSICA
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that with trim!  Cool!  +1!  :-)

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, this was starting to give me a headache! Today i learned implode and trim :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$list = explode('||',trim($list,';'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`;;CARLOS||` is the smallest match available, which is exactly what you're asking the regex engine to do. Try this regular expression:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\|\||;;)(.+?)(?=\|\||;;)/', $body, $part);

print_r($part[1]);
```

Comment: This works great!! perfect for what I'm doing, however confusing as im not sure why this works: (?<= i need to do a lot more reading. Also is it possible to get each name into its own array? perhaps by doing: `preg_match_all('\|', $part, $name_array)`

Comment: @user1294097: The `(?...)` is for *zero-width assertions*. They mean "make sure the characters specified are there, but don't actually match them". This leaves the characters for the rest of the matches. Also, if your string is exactly as shown, using `trim` and `explode` is a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `explode()` instead.

```
<?php

$string=";;CARLOS||ANDREW||STEPH||SUE||JUDY||HAROLD||JAMES||KATIE||JESSICA;;";

$names=explode("||", substr($string,2,strlen($string)-4));

print_r($names);
```

gives us:

```
Array
(
    [0] => CARLOS
    [1] => ANDREW
    [2] => STEPH
    [3] => SUE
    [4] => JUDY
    [5] => HAROLD
    [6] => JAMES
    [7] => KATIE
    [8] => JESSICA
)
```